# Converting videos to flv using ffmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

In my c# application, i am writing code for converting any video format to flv format. For this FFMPEG is used.

Some times an exceptions is occuring like:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Below is my code from where the exception throwing,

```
    IntPtr pFormatContext;
    FFmpeg.av_register_all();

    int ret;
    ret = FFmpeg.av_open_input_file(out pFormatContext, this.Filename, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

    if (ret < 0)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("couldn't open input file");

        FFmpeg.av_free_static();
        return;
    }


    try
    {
        ret = FFmpeg.av_find_stream_info(pFormatContext);

        if (ret < 0)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("couldnt find stream informaion");
            FFmpeg.av_close_input_file(pFormatContext);
            FFmpeg.av_free_static();
            return;
        }


        FFmpeg.AVFormatContext formatContext = (FFmpeg.AVFormatContext)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pFormatContext, typeof(FFmpeg.AVFormatContext));

        Duration = formatContext.duration / FFmpeg.AV_TIME_BASE;

        for (int i = 0; i < formatContext.nb_streams; ++i)
        {
            FFmpeg.AVStream stream = (FFmpeg.AVStream)Marshal.PtrToStructure(formatContext.streams[i], typeof(FFmpeg.AVStream));
            FFmpeg.AVCodecContext codec = (FFmpeg.AVCodecContext)Marshal.PtrToStructure(stream.codec, typeof(FFmpeg.AVCodecContext));

            if (codec.codec_type == FFmpeg.CodecType.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO)
            {
                Height = codec.height;
                Width = codec.width;

                        Type = FileType.flv;
                        MimeType = "video/x-flv";

            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("FFMpeg failed to understand the file");
    }

    FFmpeg.av_close_input_file(pFormatContext);
    FFmpeg.av_free_static();
}
```

And from the above code this `ret = FFmpeg.av_find_stream_info(pFormatContext);` line throws memory corrupt exception.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that `pFormatContext` is not `IntPtr.Zero` when you get the error? Does ther error raise on the same file or not?

Comment: No, it is not zero.It raises in the ret = FFmpeg.av_find_stream_info(pFormatContext);same file.

Comment: In my opinion, line you told us can raise the error only if `pFormatContext` points to a memory part that is not as expected. So, I see you check `if (ret < 0)` after `ret = FFmpeg.av_open_input_file(...)`: I think you should check `if (ret != 0)`. Let me know...

Comment: I would consider executing the command line tool using a process or using appdomain executeassembly. It would allow you to run the transcoding in a more isolated manner and you don't need to worry about protected memory.